# IIS: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a website and it sits on the IIS Server and I have a folder on another server the file server.  I have set the Virtual directory to the folder on the fileserver.  This application both servers are on the same domain, but in the future I will have serves that are not on the same domain.

I have tried to set up local users on both machines and set up the app pool to use the local accounts and I get

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
 and
 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
 You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I have set the virtual to connect as the local user and get the same error.

I have setup a domain user and then set the app pool to use the domain user and set to use pass through and when I test the settings in Directory Browsing it says everything is good but I get the same error from the webpage.

I have setup a domain user and then set the app pool to use the domain user and set to the connect as to the user and when I test the settings in Directory Browsing it says everything is good but I get the same error from the webpage.

I have set the apppool to use my login and it works with pass through permissions.

Is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the folder permissions in your separate folder to give access to the "computer$" account of the server where your application is hosted.

See here: https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

> application pool identities also use the machine account to access
>   network resources.

So in the server where you have your data files you should set the folder permissions to allow access to the machine name where your website is hosted.

Comment: Ok I have tried that I have granted Modify, Read & execute, List, and write to the Server Name and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Ok I have removed the virtual Directory, and then re-added it and set to connect as a specified user.  I created a new user on the domain that only has access to this folder.  I set the user, enter the password.  But when I test the connection I get the error that the user does not have access to the folder.  I have specifically given the user permissions to this folder.

Comment: Did you also change the permissions on the server for that folder?

Comment: Yes I have changed the permission on the the folder on the server, then from IIS I have tried to connect as the user.  I have also give permission to Domain\Servername$, as shown in the web page, but I never see DefaultAppPool as an option.

Comment: Do I have to set the virtual folder up as a shared folder?  Currently I just have permissions set for the folder but it is not a shared folder. I have also for testing set Everyone to have access to this folder but it still does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't have to, I'd you are using \\server in the virtual dir path. No harm in trying to setup a folder share and set permissions on the share.

Comment: The path is \\ServerName\FolderName\FileFolderIAmTryinhToAccess

Comment: what if its localhost (no domain) ? I set full permissions on the directory to AppPoolAccount the website is running under and still got the error :/ Its frustrating, I read all the documentation and still this easy task is nightmare :/

Answer (score 4):

I had this same challenge when deploying a web app using **IIS** on a **Windows 2012** Server.

The issue was the `App Pool Account` did not have Full rights to the `Website Root`.

All I had to do was to go to the directory where the `Website Root` resides and then right-clicked on it. Next, I selected **Security** and then gave the **IIS-Users** group full access to the directory.

For me **IIS-Users** group contains all **Users**/**App Pool Accounts** that are created in **IIS**.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I have created a domain user specifically for the the virtual directory and it appears to work, but is this best practice?